# Describe the language generated by this context-free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, formal-languages, context-free-language

I have the following grammar,

1. *`S -> Sb`*
2. *`S -> aaSb`*
3. *`S -> b`*

The typical derivations in this grammar are 
*`S => Sb => [aaSb]b => [aa[b]b]b => aabbb`* for `n = 1` 
*`S => Sb => [aaSb]b => [aa[aaSb]b]b => [aa[aabb]b]b => aaaabbbb`* for `n = 2`

Edit:
So I claimed that this grammar generates the language 
*`L = {a^(2n)b^(n+2) : n >= 1}`*

I am pretty sure that my *`a`* goes *`a^(2n)`* since there's two *`a`* before *`S`*, but what about *`b`*. There is no lambda here so my *`n`* goes from *`n >= 1`*?.

Edit: 
*`b^(n+1)`* and *`b^(2n+1)`* are both wrong assumptions because the grammar can derive a string `aaaaaabbbbb` if `n = 3`. 
I modified my *`b`* to be *`b^(n+2)`*.
so that *`L`* becomes *`L = {a^(2n)b^(n+2) : n >= 1}`*

Comment: Maybe this is new to me, but is this a software programming question?

Comment: Not really, this is more like Computer Science question.

Comment: The grammar can produce `aaaaaabbbbb` which doesn't match the form you're proposing.  (I'm pretty sure a CFG _can't_ produce a language with an exponential number of symbols, though I can't prove that in this comment.)

Comment: You are right the grammar produces `aaaaaabbbbb` if `n = 3` only if _b_  is `b^(n+2)`. So my assumption that `b^(2n)` or `b^(2n+1)` is wrong.

Comment: Production 1 means that you can add an arbitrary number of `b`s at the end. That makes an equality relationship pretty unlikely.

Comment: When they say describe _L(G)_, you have to provide a language _L_ for that grammar? Or you just explain the grammar given each production?

Comment: You can't link the number of occurrences of `a` and `b` so tightly: for any derivation from S, you can modify it to add arbitrarily many applications of production 1, which will add arbitrarily many occurrences of `b` without changing the number of `a`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language generated by this grammar is `a^(2n) b^(n+m+1)` where `n` and `m` are natural numbers. To show this, (a) we see that any string derived using the grammar's productions matches the above and (b) any string matching the above can be derived using the grammar's productions.

(a) The grammar can and must use rule (3) exactly once. This gives the `+1` in the number of `b`s. Execution of rule (2) can happen some number of times `n`, putting `2n` `a`s on the front and `n` `b`s on the back, hence the `2n` and `n` terms. Rule (1) can be executed any number of times `m`, hence the term.

(b) Given a string `a^(2n) b^(n+m+1)` for natural numbers `n` and `m`: use rule (1) a number of times equal to `m`; then, use rule (2) a number of times equal to `n`; then, user rule (3) once. Thus, the grammar generates the string.

Another way to write the same answer is `a^2n b^m` with `m > n`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to rewrite the grammar. Note that productions 1 and 2 both end in `Sb`, so we can left-factor them:

```
S -> ASb
S -> b
A -> 
A -> aa
```

From the first two productions, it's fairly easy to see that `S` generates `A^n b^{n+1} for n >= 0`.

From the last two productions, `A^n` generates `a^{2k} for 0 <= k <= n`.

So the language is `a^{2k} b^{n+1} for n >= 0, 0 <= k <= n`.

Or equivalently, let `m = n - k` to obtain `a^{2k} b^{k+m+1} for k,m >= 0`.